# TypeScript + React fetch array with different types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have three types

```
class Media {
    private _id: number;
    //getters and setters
}

class Serial extends Media {
    private _watched_series: number;
    //getters and setters
}

class Movie extends Media {
    private _watched: boolean;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And backend have the same structure. Backend return `Array<Media>`, but contains child types.

I'm trying this:

```
ListsApi.mediasFromList(list.id).then((response: Response) => {
        response.json().then((value: Array<Movie | Serial>) => {
            this.setState({medias: value});
        });
    });
```

But when I try use `typeof` I always get `object`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying write function in media `fromJson` to create object from raw json object, but then I do not understand how to determine the type of a raw object.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to determine the type of a raw JSON object, you have to manually check the properties of the object to test if it matches a specific type. The following function can be used to determine if your media is of the `Movie` type:

```
isMovie(input: Movie | Serial): input is Movie {
    return input.hasOwnProperty('_watched');
}
```

And then when you are testing if it is `Movie` or `Serial` type:

```
if (this.isMovie(media)) {
    // media will now be treated as type `Movie`
}
```